# Mockito Test RecyclerView Click Error

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, mockito

I have a test with Mockito from my `RecyclerView` clicks, but an error is thrown.

This is my code:

```
@Test
public void getUserClick() {

    RecyclerView rcv = Mockito.mock(RecyclerView.class);
    List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    User commonUser = Mockito.mock(User.class);
    commonUser.setId("1");
    commonUser.setName("User");
    commonUser.setEmail("admin@admin.com");

    usersList.add(commonUser);

    UserAdapterTest adapter = Mockito.mock(UserAdapterTest.class);
    adapter.addData(usersList);

    rcv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Test Click
    rcv.getChildAt(0).performClick();

    //Verify Click Item
    Mockito.verify(adapter).testClickItem(commonUser);
}
```

And the error launch here:

> java.lang.NullPointerException in rcv.getChildAt(0).performClick();

But the IDE doesn't tell me anything else.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.project.test.TestRecycler.getUserClick(TestRecycler.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluateSafely(JUnitRule.java:63)
at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluate(JUnitRule.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

And my adapter already has the click event implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
RecyclerView rcv = Mockito.mock(RecyclerView.class);
```

`rcv` becomes a mock (an object that returns `null` (or `0`, or `false`) by default, on any method call). So `rcv.getChildAt(0)` by default is returning `null`, and when you try to call `performClick()` on it, the `NullPointerException` occurs.

When you create a mock and want some method to return a specific value, you must tell it using `Mockito.when()`. So in your case, you should do something like this:

```
// configure "when" behaviour **before** calling the getChildAt() method
Mockito.when(rcv.getChildAt(0)).thenReturn(objectYouWantToBeReturned);
```

Obviously you need to create `objectYouWantToBeReturned` before using `when`.
The code above will make `rcv.getChildAt(0)` returns the object you want, but only if you call it with parameter `0`.

If you want to return the same object for any value (not only `0`), you can do:

```
Mockito.when(rcv.getChildAt(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(objectYouWantToBeReturned);
```

This will return `objectYouWantToBeReturned` for all calls of `getChildAt`, no matter what's the parameter value.

Comment: Thanks @Hugo, that worked!. Only have problems with the click, never call the event or i dont have form to verify that.